# storage engine: how to quickly find that key is not exist

Tags: memcached, distributed-system, distributed-caching, leveldb, rocksdb

Our distributed storage project using LevelDB as storage engine and memcached as cache layer, we have one scenario: 95% queries with keys are not exist in the storage engine.

In memcached layer, if can't find the key, then query LevelDB.

In LevelDB, we use default bloom filter to figure out the key exist or not but still have 1% false positive rate. Because of the 1% percentage, we have to request the value through IO, which can't be tolerated by client. (95% keys are not exist)

Is there any better solution to know whether the key is not exist?

Update:
1. Keys are generated everyday (userid+date), once can't get the key, then client would put the value into storage layer.
2. Client want read latency(TP99) < x ms (client is latency sensitive)

Comment: Maybe you want to record the user access per day.If so, then you can covert this "key not exist" problem to "key exist, but value not contains specified item".

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two methods which can be used to improve your solution:
1. assume that all the keys that may request are in a limited set. Maybe you can put all the keys in the set, the ones which not exist with a value like "FALSE".
2. improve your leveldb performance. adjust the size of table-cache and block-size or use ssd as storage media.
we use leveldb as persistent kv-storage in productive enviroment and support applications like blacklist which is similar to your scenario.

Comment: Thanks the recommendations. For first solution, it's impossible to do because our keys are generated everyday (key=userid+date), it's impossible to flag all the keys false. For second solution, table cache can't help because we can't find from table cache still need to request IO; the block size would little help also because bloom filter false positive is there, increase block size only increase the counts of keys, which means less find blocks, but my concern is that is there any ways to greatly avoid IO access.

Comment: I can't figure out better idea under this architecture. In fact, if I face such scenario, i will just use RAM cache system which can tolerate single failure and provide enough storage.